# Joda-Time – Remove one Period from another

Tags: java, date, jodatime, period

I am trying to remove a [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) of time from another Period of time in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), but it does not work.

```
Period p = new Period(new LocalDate("2014-01-01"), new LocalDate("2014-02-20"),PeriodType.days())
```

From this remove another Period:

```
Period minusD = new Period(new LocalDate(dates[0]), new LocalDate(dates[1]),PeriodType.days());
p.minus(minusD);
```

and now just get the days from the first period.

```
p.getDays();
```

I tried using the [MutablePeriod](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/MutablePeriod.html) as well, but that did not seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minus` does not change the given `Period` object, it creates a **new** object that's the difference between the two `Period`s:

```
Period p = new Period(/*something*/);
Period minusD = new Period(/*period to subtract*/);
Period result = p.minus(minusD);
System.out.println (result.getDays());
```